# Django Template Unable To Link to CSS

Tags: python, django

I have set the `STATICFILES_DIRS="G:/tulip/stock/static",` which is where I put my CSS but apparently the template cant find it (its 404). I have followed the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_DIRS) but no luck :(.

Can someone points me the easier way to do this?

Comment: Are you using the development server? Is debug mode on? Does STATICFILES_FINDERS include the FileSystemFinder? Are you visiting settings.STATIC_URL/myfile for a file in /tulip/stock/static/myfile?

Comment: @YujiTomita Yes, I am using development server. The debug mode is ON and the STATICFILES_FINDERS and uncommented. For the CSS link, its link this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}style/styleheet.css" />`

Comment: The exact location of the CSS is `"G:\tulip\stock\static\style\stylesheet.css"`

Comment: looks good! Does your dev server console show that requests are coming in at `MY_ACTUAL_STATIC_URL/style/stylesheet.css`? A common problem is `{{ STATIC_URL }}` not actually rendering anything since you need to use RequestContext in your view to populate that variable.

Comment: Just to make sure: You've checked that it's not just a missing `/` at the end of your `STATIC_URL`? Your href `{{ STATIC_URL }}style/styleheet.css` looks suspicious. ;)

Comment: @JohannesCharra yup, my STATIC_URL ='/static/'. Do I have to put '/static/' in url.py?

Comment: @YujiTomita the development server return this `[19/Jan/2012 16:40:36] "GET /static/style/styleheet.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1748`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it. Actually this is silly..I accidentally spelled "stylesheet" as "styleheet". Thanks tho for the help ><

Comment: Hah! Those are the hardest to find - I didn't notice the spelling error at all..

Comment: Thanks for your effort tho lol